# SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 High probability of spam with PHP mail()?

Tags: php, email-spam

This is my mail

```
$to      = $email;
$subject = "Welcome To Website";
$header  = "from: Website <contact@website.com>";
$message  = "We have created your account on Website with username,".$username."";
$message .= ". To verify your account please click on the link - ";
$url = 'http://website.com/?code=' . $code . '';
$message .= $url;
$message .= ". After Logging in you will be able to access to additional features to make the most of your Website account. If you have any question you can send us a mail or a message on our official Facebook page.";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
  return true;
}
```

Now, the mail returned true but it was not sent. When I looked further into the issue I found out that I get following error

> DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 High probability of spam

How can I avoid this? I have tried to made the email as personalized as I can with available information. Is their some other library that I should use? Is there some way I can reword the mail? I am using Cloudflare service if that can create issues with DNS or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Mail server configuration issue or blacklisting, anything can cause a mail delivery error. We’ll see how to relate to the cause, from the error message we get.

**1. Configuration errors**
"SMTP error from the remote mail server after RCPT TO::
host domain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx]: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client.
550-(host.domain.com) [yy.yy.yy.yy]: __ is not permitted to relay through this server without authentication."

**Cause:** The authentication errors mostly occur due to mail client or mail form configuration settings. If you try to send mails without proper authentication of your mail account, the mail server throws this error.

The authentication error also occurs when there is any mail server configuration issue – like domain not present in localdomains file or MX record mismatches.

**Fix:** The mail client settings should be properly configured with mail account details, SMTP server and port number. For PHP mail forms, using SMTP authentication to send out mails can help resolve this error.

To resolve mail server configuration errors, we examine the mail logs, MX records and related configuration files, and fix the discrepancies that are found in them.

**2. Domain blacklists**
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:: host host.domain.com [xx.xx.xx.xx]: 
554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [yy.yy.yy.yy] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; http://www.spamhaus.org

**Cause:** RBLs aka blacklists are used by mail servers to prevent inbound spamming. When blacklist providers such as Spamhaus suspect your mail server as a spam origin, they will blacklist your server IP.

Getting blacklisted indicates that your server had a spammer or someone who is sending mass mails. Many times, server owners get to know about it only when users complain about mail errors.

**Fix:** Once blacklisted, getting de-listed is a time-consuming procedure. Pinpointing the source of spam and fixing it is the most important step. Then you need to request RBL to remove you from the list.

Comment: None of these two error messages are related to the one given in the question. Can oyu share more details about how your answer resolves the initial problem?

Answer (score -3):

In WHM

Main >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings

See if you have "Mail authentication via domain owner password" enabled, disable it.

Also your exim_mainlog is not providing complete info.

See what you have at
Main >> Service Configuration >> Exim Configuration Manager

Advanced Editor

Search for "log_selector" and tell us what options you have there.

Also see what output this one gives:

Code:

gunzip -c /var/log/exim_mainlog.1.gz | grep 1SanWe-00042K-2C-H

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad, I can't find the Server Configuration. I am on shared Hosting. Can these settings be found in cpanel on a shared hosting account?

Comment: for this you need root access on whm, shared hosting normally have't access for that, request to your hosting provider to change that setting

Comment: What do you mean by "WHM"? How should the receiving mail server, which rejected the mail, check how the sending mail server authenticate the user?